# AngularJS: Why does my directive cannot use $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I wrote a really simple angular module that allows a tabbed-navigation (the code is simplified, but does not work either):

**module.js**

```
define(["angular","./controller","./tabs","./pane"],function(tabsController,tabs,pane){

    var module = angular.module("tabsModule",[])
    .controller("tabsController",["$scope",tabsController])
    .directive("tabs",tabs)
    //.directive("pane",pane);
    return module;
});
```

**tabs.js**

```
define([], function() {
    function tabs() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            controller: "tabsController",
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: "html/directives/tabs.html",
            link: {
                pre: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                    scope.addPane = controller.addPane.bind(controller);
                    scope.select = controller.select.bind(controller);

                }
            },
            //    transclude: true,
        };
        return directive;
    }
    return tabs;
});
```

**controller.js**

```
define(["controllers/prototypes/base_controller"],function(BaseController){
    var TabController=BaseController.extend({
        constructor:function($scope){
            BaseController.call(this,$scope);
            this.$scope.panes = [];
            this.directivesEvents=directivesEvents;
        },
        addPane:function(pane) {
            if (pane.order === 0) {
                this.$scope.select(pane);
            }
            this.$scope.panes = this.$scope.panes.concat(pane).sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.order - b.order;
            });
        },
        select:function(pane) {
            angular.forEach(this.$scope.panes, function(pane) {
                pane.selected = false;
            });
            pane.selected = true;
            this.$scope.$emit(this.directivesEvents.TAB_CHANGE, pane.id);
        }
    });
    var TabController=function($scope){

    };
    TabController.$inject=["$scope"];
    return TabController;
});
```

and I include the module in another one:

```
var directives=angular.module("directives",["tabsModule"]);
```

But when I use it, I got this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- tabsDirective

I have no idea where it comes from, I've made dozens of modules/directive, and I think I've made this one like I always do...

I'm stuck on it for hours, **please help** !!!!

**Edit:** I didn't specify it but I was using requirejs, and it was the cause of this issue.

Comment: can you provide plunk link >>?

Comment: It's working for me http://plnkr.co/edit/MWyO99jZeryqmH7viTwO?p=preview

Comment: damn! I'm gonna investigate a bit more and edit my question...

Comment: `tabsDirective` isn't taking any dependency on `$scope`, nor should it... From the angular docs, do this:    `link: { pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }, post: function postLink(scope, Element, iAttrs, controller) { ... }  }`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: btw, I already tried pre/post but it changes nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are not passing the tabs function to the directive method of angular. See the mismatch of the parameters:

```
define(["angular","./controller","./tabs","./pane"],function(tabsController,tabs,pane){
```

Instead do:

```
define(["angular","./controller","./tabs","./pane"],function(angular, tabsController, tabs, pane){
```

Comment: It looks like we unswared at the same time

Comment: yeah, but I'll give you all the glory :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I just got it, I forgot to add `angular` as parameter in `module.js`, so every argument was in the wrong place.

```
define(["angular","./controller","./tabs","./pane"],function(angular,tabsController,tabs,pane){

    var module = angular.module("tabsModule",[])
    .controller("tabsController",["$scope",tabsController])
    .directive("tabs",tabs)
    //.directive("pane",pane);
    return module;
});
```